# Why would "Go home to your wife" be translated as "Go home with your relative"?

Tags: traducción

In the Spanish translation of Twain's "Tom Sawyer," the following original passage:

> Go home to your Nance and your kids

...is translated as:

> Vete a tu casa con tu parienta, y tus chicos

...which, to me, seems to be saying, "Go home with your relative, and your children."

Did the translator not know that "Nance" was a personal name (short for "Nancy") or what?

And what would the best translation for this, anyway - something like "Vete a tu casa a tu Nance" o ""Vete a tu casa a tu esposa"?

Comment: **Parienta** is used in Spain to colloquially refer to the wife, I haven't heard it nor read it in this same sense in Latin America.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure the translator knew that Nance was a shortened form for Nancy; otherwise he couldn't have translated it as *parienta*, a rather colloquial form for *wife*. The word *pariente* meaning *relative* is almost always used with the *-e* ending, it has no feminine form except to refer to *la [parienta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RwLAmmj)*:

> 4. m. y f. coloq. Esposo con relación al otro miembro del matrimonio.

In this sense it is almost always used in feminine. I have never seen "mi pariente" used to refer to someone's husband, at least in Spain.

So, why using *parienta*? Because literary works are not translated, but adapted. If I had to choose between "vete a casa con Nancy", "vete a casa con tu Nancy" or "vete a casa con tu mujer", all the choices are correct but there are slight difference in meaning:

- "Vete a casa con Nancy" sounds conforting, and it implies that both people know Nancy closely.
- "Vete a casa con tu Nancy" sounds a bit despective towards Nancy.
- "Vete a casa con tu mujer" sounds between neutral and conforting, but it implies that the speaker does not know Nancy in a close way (maybe he does not even know her name), which might be the case in the novel. Could *Nance* be used in the novel as a generic way to refer to someone's wife when you do not know her name?

And using *parienta* is just because it is a very colloquial way to say *wife*, and it fits very well with the low-level language used in the village where the *Tom Sayer* novel takes place.

Comment: I personally suspect it's a slang term for one's wife, or if not that the name of the fellow's wife. *But*, I've also heard it attested as slang (really, an offensive slur) for a gay man, and I've found sources that suggest it's from the 19th century, so I wonder whether that interpretation is possible.

Comment: @Obie2.0 I know, I discovered that while researching the term for [a question I asked](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/475544/280768) in the English language site.

Comment: In the Mikado by Gilbert and Sullivan the line occurs, "with his Nancy on his knee" which I have always assumed just meant his female nearest and dearest but I am not sure. The line is sometimes these days the cause of homophobic sniggers from the audience.